# find the position of a text link in the powerpoint presentation

Tags: vba, hyperlink, powerpoint

I want to know if there is a way to get the position where a hyperlink is set. In the case of the Shapes they have top and left values, and I can select hyperlinks with Slides(i).Hyperlinks but I cannot find the way to find the position of the hyperlinks that I find in the presentation as I can do with the shapes. Is there a way to do it?

Comment: your hyperlinks are text within text box (or shape), or you have different type of hyperlinks? if they are text within text box you have top/left of that shape- isn't that enough? do you need exact position of what- left/top corner of first left letter??

Comment: the proble is that I don't know what shape is the one who have the hyperlink... and I will need to find the position just of the hyperlink in the case of a text link no the whole textbox

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to look at each hyperlink's type to determine whether it's a hyperlinked shape or a hyperlink applied to text. You already know how to deal with the shapes, but if it's text, you have to walk up the parent chain to find the textrange the hyperlink's applied to.  The textrange's BoundLeft, BoundTop, BoundWidth and BoundHeight properties will tell you where the text is.

Note: if you do this in PPT 2007 with no service packs, PPT will disappear.  Poof.  Gone.

```
Dim oHl As Hyperlink
Dim oSl As Slide
Dim oRng As TextRange
Set oSl = ActivePresentation.Slides(1)

For Each oHl In oSl.Hyperlinks
    With oHl
        If .Type = msoHyperlinkRange Then
            Debug.Print TypeName(.Parent)
            Debug.Print TypeName(.Parent.Parent)
            Debug.Print TypeName(.Parent.Parent.Parent)
            Debug.Print TypeName(.Parent.Parent.Parent.Parent)
            Set oRng = .Parent.Parent
            Debug.Print oRng.Text
            Debug.Print oRng.BoundLeft
            Debug.Print oRng.BoundTop
        Else
            ' it's a hyperlinked shape

        End If
    End With
Next
```

Comment: that is exactly the answer... +1 from me and hope Iban will add the other points :)

Comment: Yes indeed... this is the answer I was looking for! Thanks!!